# Codeigniter pagination link is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CI so guys request to help me in displaying result for pagination link. In database, I have 3 records I'm displaying a single record for each page.
Problem is in my pagination link when i select next numeric link of pagination, result is not being displayed.

Thing is that that when I click on number 2 of pagination link output shows results is empty and I am not getting any values for echo $data->email.Below is my controller,model,view.

I have tried many ways but no use i even completely follwed google even though no use.
I think the problem is when the page is loading to get second record from database when the pagination link is selected post values are no more passing to model page so might be the problem.

**Here is my controller.**

```
public function users($limit=1,$offset){
 $this->load->helper('url');
 $this->load->view('includes/kheader');
 $this->load->view('includes/kmenu');
 $data = array();

    $look = $this->input->post('look');
    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
    $age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
    $se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
    $subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
    $coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
    $sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
    $ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
    $qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');
    $results = $this->searchresultss->login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification);
   //for base_url()
    $this->load->helper('url');
   //Pagination Config
    $config = array();
   // $config['base_url'] = base_url().'searchresult/users';
   $config['base_url'] = base_url().'searchresult/users';
    $config['total_rows'] = count($results);
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $this->load->library('pagination', $config);
    $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
     //Reducing the number of results for the view
    /** NOTE: This is not the most efficient way **/
    //echo $data;
    $data['results'] = array_slice($results,$offset,$limit);
$this->load->view('searchresult', $data);
```

**Here is my model page**

```
public function login($look, $age, $age_to, $age_from, $se_ct, $subsect, $coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty, $qualification)
            {
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE   gender = '$look' And status='1'")->result();
            }
```

I'm not able to get an answer through google too But one record is being displayed when the page load's problem is when I select pagination link of next numeric link it is not working. Pagination script is not working properly i think it is related to offset. 
So what might be the error I'm not sure so I am posting my code below please go through it and and help me.

//Error is when I select next numeric link of pagination ,record is not being fetched from database I am getting output as empty result in my view page.so request you to help me in solving the issue and more warning message is  missing argument 2 for Searchresult::users() , and more error message is undefined variable offset .

**Here is view page**

```
if (empty($results)) {
    echo 'Results set is empty';
} else {
foreach ($results as $data) {
        echo $data->email.'<br />';
    }
}
echo $pagination_links;
```

Has I am new to ci iam looking for a ci developer who can sought my problem if there are any mistakes please don't mind.

Comment: where you defined `$offset` and `$limit`? Why you are paginating from array? instead of database? Do you know you can reduce the query load to implement the pagination into the database query?

Comment: Actually ia completely new to php ,ci  i have defeined $ limit at function but i dint defined $offset..can u briefly explain what changes to be done

Comment: You should cover up the basics first, https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html And you should define the both variable in the same method, instead of somewhere else or your can define it in the same class as public variable. So that you can access it anywhere in the same class.

Comment: public function users($limit=1,$offset=0) i defined in this way bt no use

Comment: it seems you can't familiar with classes and how to use?

Comment: check this tutorial for creating pagination work with search query string http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings--net-18275 best way to use for search

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
        // Pagination Library
        $this->load->library('pagination'); 

        $Row_Per_Page = $this->rpp; // or direct assign 10 as int


        $Page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        // Only for Query String ?page=2&parm=val&parm2=val2
        $this->pagination->suffix = ! empty($QS) ? "?" . $QS : "";


        // Configuration Settings
        $config['base_url'] = base_url("cpanel/invoices");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->invoice->invoices_count($QS);
        $config['per_page'] = $Row_Per_Page;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link']  = '&laquo;';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:;">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // Pass variables to query 
        // $config["per_page"] -> Row Per Page
        // $Page -> Holds the Starting Limit from URI Segment
        $this->settings['Invoices'] = $this->invoice->get_invoice_list( $config["per_page"], $Page, $this->input->server('QUERY_STRING') ); 
        $this->settings['Pagination_Link'] = $this->pagination->create_links();




        $this->load->view('cpanel/invoice_lists', $this->settings );
```

Read the comments between the codes for better understand. Hope this help you.